# html hash reference positions element underneath navbar

Tags: html

I am using a hash reference to scroll to a specific part of my website, but it scrolls so that the hash is at the top of window, which in underneath my nav bar. So the title of the element I was hash referencing is hidden and that doesn't look good.

Is there any way to give a top margin or something similar to a hash reference so that it loads at the right spot?

I've tried putting line breaks within the div but since there is a background colour on the div, it extends the background above the title and also looks bad.

Thanks in advance for your help!

html:
     Item 1

```
<div id="item1">
    <h4>item1 title</h4>
    <p>item1 content</p> 
</div>
```

css:

```
:target {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
```

As you can see the issue with padding is that when the has reference is selected the above CSS is applied to it. With padding this background colour and border is applied around the whole div (including the padding) and looks bad.

Any solution to this problem?

Even if I add another div surrounding Item 1 like so:

```
<a href="#item1"> Item 1 </a>

<div id="item1" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="I want only this div with coloured background">
    <h4>item1 title</h4>
    <p>item1 content</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

The :target psuedo-element still selects the whole div and colours the padding background.

Comment: You should be able to put it in it's own div and then apply a margin to the top of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use padding on the top of the element you're linking to in order to offset the navbar if you're sticking to just HTML.

If that's not an option you'd have to use a javascript solution. I just wrote this up real quick, requires jQuery. The 50 would be the height of the navbar.

```
$('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this), $target = $($this.attr('href'));
  $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 50
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: The issue is I'm using the :target pseudo-class which still selects the padding. See revised code above. Not sure if I can tell :target to select the inside div? So far my efforts haven't worked.

Comment: and thanks for the javascript! But when I put it in my page none of the hash references work anymore (I just copied and pasted exactly as is, I don't have much js experience to know if it should be changed. I do have Jquery referenced in my scripts.

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Need css:

:target > div {...}

With padding at top.

Comment: I just fixed the script, but then realized it wouldn't help your situation with :target. You'd need to play around with the hashchange event. I think you ended up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the markup with the surrounding div and change the CSS like this:

```
:target > div {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not add a margin to the h4 element? If every div you're linking to starts with a h4 title, then do something like

```
div h4:first-child{margin-top:20px;}
```